# multiple blocks in template

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

How can I declare a region in the template to use in other template files?

Basically, I want 2 regions in my template to use for `container` and `container-fluid` classes of bootstrap.

Right now i declare a div with `container` class in the `header.php` file and close the div in the `footer.php`.So everything is inside the `container` div.

In `Twig` I can use the following syntax:

```
<div class="container">

{% block container %}

{% endblock %}

</div>

<div class="container-fluid">

    {% block container-fluid %}

    {% endblock %}

</div>
```

and in child templates just put the content in the block

```
{% block container-fluid %}

// my content

{%endblock %}
```

Comment: Sounds like [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/).

Answer (score 0):

Using loop.php in child themes
Assuming the theme folder is wp-content/themes, that the parent theme is twentyten, and the child theme is twentytenchild, then the following code —

```
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>
```

will do a PHP require() for the first file that exists among these, in this priority:

wp-content/themes/twentytenchild/loop-index.php

wp-content/themes/twentyten/loop-index.php

wp-content/themes/twentytenchild/loop.php

wp-content/themes/twentyten/loop.php